# How to handle duplicate forward slashes on url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `React` and I'm trying to handle duplicate forward slashes on my website similar to Facebook. Its works like this:

If the user acess: `https://facebook.com///settings` the url is updated to `https://facebook.com/settings`

I'm trying to do this overriding the `window.location.pathname` like this:

```
const pattern = /\/+[/]/;
const urlFinal = window.location.pathname.replace(pattern, "");
window.location.pathname = urlFinal;
```

But it returns an infinite loop of refresh on the window.

So, how can I do that? Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave a slash:

```js
let pathName = window.location.pathname;
const pattern = /\/+[/]/;
const urlFinal = pathname.replace(pattern, "/");
if (urlFinal.length < pathName) window.location.pathname = urlFinal;
```

Comment: It still looped :/

Comment: Please see test I added